# jquery animation not working right after the second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I was trying to slide down my header when I click on the wrapper and then when I click again it slides up. It's only working when I click the first time, then it keeps sliding down again the header.

here is the code:

```
var header = $("header");
$("wrapper").on("click", function () {
    if (header.css({"top" : "-8%"})) {
        header.animate({"top" : "0%"}, 500);
    } else if (header.css("top") == '0%') {
        header.animate({"top" : "-8%"}, 500);
    };
});
```

Comment: `if (header.css({"top" : "-8%"}))` always evaluates to true so you will always catch the first animate call

Comment: Yeah, you wrote `(header.css({"top" : "-8%"}))` when you meant `(header.css("top") == '-8%')`.

Comment: And you both put your answers in comments for some reason. Who's being silliest?

Comment: man, still don't work TT @PatrickGunderson I've tried with your answers but still not working mates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
$(".wrapper").click( function ()
{
    if ( $(".header").css( 'top' ) == '-8%' )
        $(".header").animate( {'top' : '0%'}, 500);
    else
        $(".header").animate( {'top' : '-8%'}, 500);
} );
```

I've supposed that 'wrapper' and 'header' were classes that's why i've added $(".header"). If you've tagged them, write $("#header").

Sorry for my english, i'm French.